# Qtile doesn't install on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: debian, ubuntu, python, window-manager

I'm trying to install Qtile on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04. According to the [Qtile installation documentation](http://docs.qtile.org/en/latest/manual/install/ubuntu.html), Qtile is no longer supported by `apt`, and an installation from source is advised. Instructions are provided [here](http://docs.qtile.org/en/latest/manual/install/index.html#installing-from-source).

When I follow those instructions to the letter, I get an error that the command errored out with the following message:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/yehuda/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-kvdwotq7/qtile_78329e7437d44395920938573a2554c8/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-kvdwotq7/qtile_78329e7437d44395920938573a2554c8/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ja04qda9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/yehuda/anaconda3/include/python3.8/qtile
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-kvdwotq7/qtile_78329e7437d44395920938573a2554c8/
    Complete output (21 lines):
    Failed to find pulseaudio headers. PulseVolume widget will be unavailable
    running install
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-kvdwotq7/qtile_78329e7437d44395920938573a2554c8/setup.py", line 91, in <module>
        setup(
      File "/home/yehuda/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/home/yehuda/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/home/yehuda/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/home/yehuda/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 984, in run_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/home/yehuda/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-kvdwotq7/qtile_78329e7437d44395920938573a2554c8/setup.py", line 46, in finalize_options
        if not self.cairo_xcb_check():
      File "/tmp/pip-install-kvdwotq7/qtile_78329e7437d44395920938573a2554c8/setup.py", line 40, in cairo_xcb_check
        cairo.cairo_xcb_surface_create
    ffi.error: symbol 'cairo_xcb_surface_create' not found in library 'libcairo.so.2': /home/yehuda/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/../../libcairo.so.2: undefined symbol: cairo_xcb_surface_create
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/yehuda/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-kvdwotq7/qtile_78329e7437d44395920938573a2554c8/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-kvdwotq7/qtile_78329e7437d44395920938573a2554c8/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ja04qda9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/yehuda/anaconda3/include/python3.8/qtile Check the logs for full command output.
```

What is happening, and how can I properly install Qtile on a Debian-Ubuntu system?

Comment: What is the method that you are using to perform the install?

Comment: looks like your cairo may have been built without xcb support, which is odd because the official package has xcb as a dependency. so unless you've built your own cairo at some point this explanation feels unlikely

Comment: I'm also having this problem, please share a solution if you ever find one op

Comment: @NasirRiley I’m following the commands in the link I posted in the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04. I solved the problem by installing python3 and pip3 as system packages, before that I had only used anaconda and had it's base environment sourced in my `.bashrc`. I successfully installed qtile doing the following:

```bsh
sudo apt install python3 python3-distutils
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py  # I got a warning that /home/$USER/.local/bin wasn't on path so I added that in my .bashrc
pip3 install xcffib
pip3 install --no-cache-dir cairocffi
pip3 install dbus-next
pip3 install qtile
```

That worked for me. Don't forget to source your `.bashrc` after changing it!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but after a bit finding I got it working

```
sudo apt install pip
pip install xcffib
pip install qtile
sudo cd /usr/share/xsessions/
sudo touch qtile.desktop
sudo echo "[Desktop Entry]
Name=Qtile
Comment=Qtile Session
Exec=qtile start
Type=Application
Keywords=wm;tiling" >> qtile.desktop
```

Also add the following to the start of `~/.bashrc` :

```
PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Just copy and paste the above commands into your terminal, and it will take care of the installation process for you. [If you also want to use my Qtile configuration, you can find it here](https://github.com/muhiris/dotfiles).

I hope this helps others who might face similar issues with Qtile installation on Linux Mint!